# How do I force Visual.VisualTransform to be regenerated in WPF rendering tree?

Tags: c#, wpf

I just added a Visual into the rendering tree that has a translation... for some reason the VisualTransform is null so TransformToAncestor comes back with the wrong value.  How do I force the VisualTransform to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first check the order in which your objects are placed. If the transform exist and is triggered before the control exist, it won't be executed. There is also an update method on the visual to refresh it.

Comment: It's the other way around by calling the InvalidateVisual method. But it seems that it don't work according to this post. See Douglas solution here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/bf265395-3088-4001-8656-806d344ad9b7/